# Update center behind proxy : howto with https bintray repository?

Tags: sonarqube

Recently, SonarQube uses the bintray repository for package distribution, **in https** (see [update-center.properties](http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties)).

Using the update center behind a proxy, some updates are found but when upgrade, error (here for xml plugin) :

```
Fail to download the plugin (xml, version 1.3) from https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonar-xml-plugin/sonar-xml-plugin-1.3.jar (error is : Fail to download: https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonar-xml-plugin/sonar-xml-plugin-1.3.jar (no proxy))
```

The SonarQube:[DefaultHttpDownloader](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-core/src/main/java/org/sonar/core/util/DefaultHttpDownloader.java#L153) seems not support **https.proxyXXX properties**.

---

**Is there today a mean to use the update center for these plugins ?**

---

@SonarSource : This feature could be supported in `sonar.properties` for the future ? Or declare http url for bintray repository (but evil) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The properties `https.proxyHost` and `https.proxyPort` are finally supported in SonarQube 5.5. Thanks Alix for the feedback.
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7429

Answer (score 25):

> Is there today a mean to use the update center for these plugins ?

In `sonar.properties` use `sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts` parameter to declare `https.proxyXXX` properties :

```
sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.company.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyUser=myUser -Dhttps.proxyPassword=myPassword
```

**NB** :

- `https.proxyUser`/`https.proxyPassword` are useless if the same as `http.proxyUser`/`http.proxyPassword` further in the configuration.
- This answer has been tested with SonarQube **v4.5** series

---

Perhaps one day some specific properties will be available in SonarQube config :-).

Comment: Should I restat server after I change the setting above?

Comment: @Naggi : I think yes (but not verified), because this is a JVM start argument.

Comment: Works on SonarQube 5.3

Comment: @jeffporter : You means this workaround is useless with v5.3 (I will do an update in this case), or that this workaround works with v5.3 (too) ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I tried updating sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts in sonar.properties, but the settings were not picked up (using sonarqube:5.1.1 docker image).

I had to adapt the startup script:

My docker command:

```
RUN sed -i -e 's/-Djava.security.egd=/-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.mycompany.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.mycompany.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Djava.security.egd=/g' /opt/sonarqube/bin/run.sh
```

Comment: Yes, the settings in the sonar.properties file are not picked up because run.sh actually overrides them.