# SonarQube 5.3 - Download plugins behind proxy (HTTPS)

Tags: configuration, proxy, sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

There are a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296136/update-center-behind-proxy-howto-with-https-bintray-repository) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495468/sonarqube-proxy-configuration-tricky) about this already, but none of the provided solutions work with SonarQube v5.3.

So far I've tried setting `sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.XXX -Dhttps.proxyPort=YYY`, both `http(s).proxyHost=proxy.XXX` and `http(s).proxyPort=YYY`.

It's important to notice that when SonarQube is starting (I'm running the docker app) it tries to connect to `http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties`, in which case I'm able to check that **http** proxy works:

```
sonar_1 | 2016.02.29 20:46:18 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (HTTP proxy: proxy.XXX:YYY)
```

But, when trying to download any plugin from Update Center, it fails:

```
sonar_1 | org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to download the plugin (ldap, version 1.5.1) from https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonar-ldap-plugin/sonar-ldap-plugin-1.5.1.jar (error is : Fail to download: https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonar-ldap-plugin/sonar-ldap-plugin-1.5.1.jar (no proxy))
```

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: Adding relevant debug logs according to the configuration been used.

- Using only `sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=-Dhttps.proxyHost=http://proxy.XXX -Dhttps.proxyPort=YYY -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.XXX -Dhttp.proxyPort=YYY`: [gist](https://gist.github.com/resilva87/4b5e85339ed0f3075b74)
- Using `http.proxyHost`, `http.proxyPort`, `https.proxyHost` and `https.proxyPort`: [gist](https://gist.github.com/resilva87/59955941e8662c2f97a9)

Comment: General guidelines aside, to focus on a precise issue: can you set `http.proxyHost/Port` _and_ `https.proxyHost/Port` in `sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts` , switch `sonar.log.level` to `DEBUG` and share some more logs of the failure ?

Comment: @n_stan sure, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTPS proxy properties (`https.proxyHost` and `https.proxyPort`) **must** be set in `sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts` because they are not understood/suppoerted in `sonar.properties`.

The HTTP proxy properties (`http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort`) can be set either in `sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts` or in `sonar.properties` directly.

Careful though: if you set the HTTP ones in `sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts`, make sure to comment out the `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort` lines in `sonar.properties`. Otherwise the latter would override the former (and I feel like this is what might be happening in your [gist1](https://gist.github.com/resilva87/4b5e85339ed0f3075b74) ).

**Edit**: you're running SonarQube in a docker container, in which case `sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts` are [currently set](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/blob/22423d6af65fbf54fcc8ce498c4cfe126d74b42f/5.3/run.sh) in the `run.sh` script. For additional Java properties you'll have to modify this directly.

Comment: Actually **none** of the options I used worked. As the gists show, I've tried both solutions. gist1 shows only `sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts` being defined.

Comment: Can you share the `sonar.properties` you're using in gist1 ?

Comment: Not quite, I meant the full `sonar.properties` file, where all other properties are defined. To have a view of all the properties passed to SonarQube in gist1 scenario.

Comment: Well, that's all there is. The file has only those 2 lines

Comment: ok. Can you share full server startup logs from first line all the way down to the error shown in gist1 ? Thanks

Comment: n-stan I've updated the gists with full log. I don't know if that's too important but I'm running SonarQube in a Docker container. http proxy seems to work fine.

Comment: You think your `sonar.properties` is taken into account but it's not. The `sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts` are not seen in the `Launch process[web]` line. Hint: your SonarQube points to `jdbc:mysql://db:3306/` which is not the default, where is this configured (since it's not in those 2 lines of properties) ?

Comment: Ok, it's likely due to how the Docker container works: `sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts` are passed in the `run.sh` script, answer edited.

Comment: n_stan - you're partially correct. Actually, only the `sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts` was not being selected from `sonar.properties` file, as it was being defined by `run.sh`. I'll submit a PR to sonarqube docker team to check if they can remove this setting from `run.sh`